# radio button not working properly using with bootstrap 4 and vue.js

Tags: php, vue.js

i am making a test portal with php and vue.js ,my radio button is not working properly,when i select the first question and goes with second question ,my first radio button is delselect.

1.Here active_question is array which contaion my current question .
 2.{{ active_question.ch1 }} , {{ active_question.ch2 }},{{ active_question.ch3 }} ,{{ active_question.ch4 }} is my options.
3.when i click to save&next button my second question is show ,if i select second question answer ,my firsr radio button was deselect.

```
 <div class="row tab-content container-fluid tab-pane active" id="section1">
            <div class="col s6 m6 l6 "> 
                <div class="row">
                    <div  class="card col s12 " style="background-color: #3e51b5;color: white;width: 600px;height:50px; margin-left:20px;margin-right: 20px;font-size:20px;">
                        <center> <p>
                                <b> Question:&nbsp;{{active_question.index}}</b>
                            </p></center>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <br>
                <div class="row">
                    <div  class="card col s12 " style="background-color: #EAEAEA;width: 600px;height:300px; margin-left:20px;margin-right: 20px;font-size:20px; ">
                        <center> <p>
                                <b> <?php
                                    echo nl2br("{{ active_question.question }}");
                                    ?></b>
                            </p></center>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col s12 m6 l6 "> 
                <div class="row">
                    <div  class="card col s12 m12 l12" style="background-color: #3e51b5;color: white;height:50px; margin-left:20px;margin-right: 20px;font-size:20px;">
                        <center> <p >
                                <b> Options</b>
                            </p></center>
                    </div> 
                </div>
                <br>   

                <div>


                    <form>



                        <div class="row " >
                            <div  class="card col s12 m12 l12" style="background-color: #EAEAEA;overflow-x: auto;width: 400px;height:100px; margin-left:20px;margin-right: 20px;font-size:20px; ">
                                <div> 
                                    <button class="button" id="qusbtn">A</button>
                                    <input type="radio"   v-model='userResponses' v-bind:id="'userSelect_'+active_question.index"   v-bind:name="'userSelect_'+active_question.index"  v-bind:value="{ques_id: active_question.ques_id, selectanswer: active_question.ch1}">       
                                    <label  for="options1"  ><div style="text-align: justify;">{{ active_question.ch1 }}</div></label>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <br>
                        <div class="row ">
                            <div  class="card col s12 m12 l12" style="background-color: #EAEAEA;width: 400px;height:100px; margin-left:20px;margin-right: 20px;font-size:20px; ">
                                <div>
                                    <button class="button " id="qusbtn">B</button>
                                    <input type="radio"   v-model='userResponses'  v-bind:id="'userSelect_'+active_question.index"  v-bind:name="'userSelect_'+active_question.index" v-bind:value="{ques_id: active_question.ques_id, selectanswer: active_question.ch2}">       
                                    <label for="options2" >{{ active_question.ch2 }}</label>
                                </div>             
                            </div>               
                        </div>
                        <br>
                        <div class="row "  >
                            <div  class="card col s12 m12 l12" style="background-color: #EAEAEA;width: 400px;height:100px; margin-left:20px;margin-right: 20px;font-size:20px; ">               
                                <div>
                                    <button class="button " id="qusbtn">C</button>
                                    <input type="radio"   v-model='userResponses' v-bind:id="'userSelect_'+active_question.index" v-bind:name="'userSelect_'+active_question.index"    v-bind:value="{ques_id: active_question.ques_id, selectanswer: active_question.ch3}">       
                                    <label  for="options3" >{{ active_question.ch3 }}</label>
                                </div>             
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <br>
                        <div class="row ">
                            <div  class="card col s12 m12 l12" style="background-color: #EAEAEA;width: 400px;height:100px; margin-left:20px;margin-right: 20px;font-size:20px; ">
                                <div>
                                    <button class="button " id="qusbtn">D</button>
                                    <input type="radio"  v-model='userResponses' v-bind:id="'userSelect_'+active_question.index"   v-bind:name="'userSelect_'+active_question.index"      v-bind:value="{ques_id: active_question.ques_id, selectanswer: active_question.ch4}">       

                                    <label for="options4" >{{ active_question.ch4 }}</label> 
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>  

                        <label class="btn btn-info active">
                            <input checked type="radio" v-model='userResponses' v-bind:id="'userSelect_'+active_question.index"   v-bind:name="'userSelect_'+active_question.index" >
                        </label>


                    </form>

                </div>


            </div>

        </div>
```

Comment: Where is your second question?

Comment: active_question is my array which contain my current question., when i click to save and next button my second is show , now if i select second questio my first radio button is deselect. r u getting my point ??